# saving toggle button and textView state

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I'm new on android. I want to change the color of a text when a toggle button is checked and then save the state of both toggle button and text color even when the app is killed. can somebody give me some tips of how to do that. thanks.

Comment: This question is too broad. What have you tried?

Comment: use shared prefs to store the state and get it back again from it whenever required !!

Answer (score 0):

here is simple example of toggle button and text view with Preferences(for save state).

create layout file below way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textItem;
    SharedPreferences sPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        // init Preferences
        sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        // init view
        textItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ToggleButton syncSwitch = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        // toggle button event
        syncSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // set text color method
                setTextColor(isChecked);
                // save Toggle button state in Preference
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("ToggleButton_CHECK", isChecked);
                ed.commit();
            }
        });

        // set default color if TextView called when activity started only for first time
        boolean saveState = sPref.getBoolean("ToggleButton_CHECK", false);
        setTextColor(saveState);
        syncSwitch.setChecked(saveState);
    }

    public void setTextColor(boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // button is on
            textItem.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.agro_purple));
        } else {
            // button is off
            textItem.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Hope it help!